# Convert TAG to FIELD in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to convert a tag (which is string) to make field (like double) which would contain a transformed version of the tag value? Like an QL update expression?

Comment: Likely not possible - now update query exists in the QL...

Answer (score 5):

One could use `influx_inspect export` to dump the database in the [line protocol format](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/). Then relevant columns could be grepped and modified with your favorite tool, like python or sed/bash. And the modified time series could be re-inserted directly into the database (one could use `split -l 7000` to split field time series into chunks and the use `curl -POST .../write?db=... --data-binary @chunk` and iterate over those chunks expecting HTTP 204 for correctly inserted values).

Answer (score 4):

This is only possibly using [Kapacitor](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.2/)

```
stream()
  |from()
    .measurement('mymeasurement')
  |log() // outputs the current state of the pipelie
  |eval(lambda: float("mytag"))
    .as('myfield')
    .keep()
  |log()
```