# Influxdb: how to convert field to tag

Tags: influxdb

How can I convert field to tag in my measurements?
I have a field 'name' which has to to be converted into a tag 'name'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert TAG to FIELD in InfluxDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392682/convert-tag-to-field-in-influxdb)